# ROS Answers SE migration: rosdoc fails

Tags: ros, rosdoc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte. I installed ROS desktop full and documentation using apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full ros-fuerte-documentation
```

When I try to use rosdoc, I get the following error:

```
$ rosrun rosdoc rosdoc turtlesim
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/rdcore.py:43: UserWarning: roslib.rospack is deprecated, please use rospkg
  import roslib.rospack
initializing rosdoc context:
    package filters: ['turtlesim']
    path filters: []
+package[turtlesim]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/__init__.py", line 134, in main
    artifacts = generate_docs(ctx)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/__init__.py", line 83, in generate_docs
    import doxygenator
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/doxygenator.py", line 334, in <module>
    header_template = load_tmpl(header_template_name())
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/doxygenator.py", line 199, in header_template_name
    major, minor, patch = doxygen_version.split('.')
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

My Doxygen version is 1.7.6.1

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34295/rosdoc-fails/) by [Flo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2404/flo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am seeing this, too, with Fuerte on Precise.

I am fairly certain it works better with Fuerte on Oneiric.

We should open a defect ticket on the documentation stack.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-22**:
Ticket created: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3969

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For your interest. I had the same error (http://answers.ros.org/question/34020/rosdoc-fuerte-python-valueerror/) and also created a ticket (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5451).
I added a patch that solves the error on both tickets.

Tinne

---

Originally posted by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) with karma: 198 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-23**:
Thanks for the patch. I missed your ticket because I was looking in ros and not ros-pkg. One of them should probably be closed as a duplicate. I guess Melonee will decide which.

**Comment by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on 2012-05-23**:
Yes indeed. Sorry for misplacing the ticket.
I also tried to markt it as duplicate but I did not find the correct buttons :S

**Comment by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on 2012-05-23**:
For your interest. I added an improved patch (the old one was not working for doxygen versions not containing a build number). The new patch should work in all cases.